# Insert inclined image in another one

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I bought this image in Fotolia : https://fr.fotolia.com/id/109276839

I want to insert an screenshot in the computer screen of Fotolia image.

Do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: Are you aware PS has a "Free Transform" function? If you tried that, how did it not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add your image on top of the fotolio picture, and "convert it to smart object".
[image]

2) WIth your image selected, do "CTRL + T" to activate the free transform. Put your cursor on each corner of the free transform, And while holding CTRL*, click and drag each point to match the edges of the computer image.

PS: your cursor should turn to white triangle, when you press CTRL. This is to activate the perspective transform.
[image]
[image]
[image]

3) Once you done, putting the picture in perspective, Add a shape layer as you see on the image on top of all your images
[image]

4)Give it a "gradient layer style" with the settings that you see on the image, then create a "clipping mask" by pressing CTRL+ALT+G, and set the fill at 0%
[image]

5) Finnally, set the opacity of the Shape layer at 30%
[image]